# existe alguna manera de conectarme a mi propio servidor local a traves de la terminal de Linux

Tags: servidor, shell, terminal

Me explico: necesito ejecutar un script en el cual debo listar las base de datos para luego exportarlas con mysqldump, el problema es que para probarlo quisiera hacerlo en local, antes de subirlo al servidor remoto. existe alguna manera de conectarme a mi propio servidor local y ejecutar comandos incluso de mysql? trabajo con Linux, tengo xampp instalado, administro las bd con phpmyadmin. antes de pasar por aca revise en Google pero no halle una informacion, asi que no se si es posible, por eso acudo a ustedes. gracias de antemano. saludos!

Comment: `ssh usuario@localhost`, si da error : `ssh -vvv usuario@localhost` ( las 3 v es para que el ssh sea mas verborrágico y asi ves que puede ser el problema )

Comment: Debo colocar el puerto? donde puedo ver cual es el nombre del usuario de mi servidor local?

Comment: @JulianProg es tu usuario. Que quieres decir? Tu servidor local es la maquina que estas usando, no?

Comment: el puerto ssh suele ser el 22, para saber tu user escribe `whoami`, o podés excluir el usuario y te toma el actual: `ssh localhost`

Comment: ok, intente con ssh localhost y nada, me muestra este error:  ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused , tambien intente con ssh -p 22 localhost y muestra el mismo error.

Comment: ponle las `-vvv` asi te cuenta mas del error, tal vez necesites instalar el servidor ssh

Comment: sólo para estar seguros, estás en un entorno (escritorio) linux y tu stack xampp es local, cierto?

Comment: si te quieres conectar vía ssh, hace falta que tu equipo tenga instalado un servidor ssh, por ejemplo, `sshd`. Un saludo.

Comment: ya logre conectar, no tenia el servidor ssh instalado. ahora el problema viene cuando intento conectarme a la base de datos me daba error, imagino porque no tenia instalado el cliente mysql en mi computadora, pero al intentar instalarlo con el comando: sudo apt-get install mysql-client no se termina de instalar, me muestra error: Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 mysql-server-5.7 , mysql-server . que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Tu servidor local es simplemente un otro servidor como cualquiera. Entonces, te puedes conectar tal cual como lo hicieras normalmente, usando el IP o el nombre del servidor. Por ejemplo, para conectarte con tu usuario actual:

```
ssh miservidor.midominio.com
```

O

```
ssh 123.456.7.8
```

O, con otro usuario:

```
ssh usuario@miservidor.midominio.com
```

O:

```
ssh usuario@123.456.7.8
```

Como esto es tu servidor local, es decir la maquina en la cual estas, tambien puedes usar el `localhost` o el IP especial `127.0.0.1`:

```
ssh localhost
ssh 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: intente con: ssh localhost y me muestra este error: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused, intenté tambien con: ssh -p 22 localhost y me muestra: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused.

Comment: @JulianProg no hace falta el `-p 22`, el 22 es el puerto por defecto. Para poderte conectar por ssh, necesitas una maquina que puede manejar conexiones ssh. El error sugiere que no tienes el servidor ssh activado en tu servidor.

Comment: ya logre conectar, no tenia el servidor ssh instalado. ahora el problema viene cuando intento conectarme a la base de datos me daba error, imagino porque no tenia instalado el cliente mysql en mi computadora, pero al intentar instalarlo con el comando: sudo apt-get install mysql-client no se termina de instalar, me muestra error: Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 mysql-server-5.7 , mysql-server . que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: @JulianProg abre otra pregunta por esto por favor, aunque creo que no sera tópica aquí. Mejor intentar (en Ingles) en [ubuntu.se] o [unix.se].